# Python - Write into txt file for my list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, file, dictionary

Suppose I have the list of dictionaries dataset that is stored like this:

```
data = [
 {'Name': 'Sneaker shoes', 'Date & Time': '2019-12-03 18:21:26', 'Information': ['Sizes from 38 to 44', 'Comes in 5 different colour', 'Rated 4.3 out of 5 stars']}, 
 {'Name': 'Worker boots', 'Date & Time': '2018-11-05 10:12:15', 'Information': ['Sizes from 38 to 44', 'Comes in 2 different colour', 'Rated 3.7 out of 5 stars']},
 {'Name': 'Slippers', 'Date & Time': '2018-10-05 13:15:44', 'Information': ['Sizes from 38 to 42', 'Comes in 3 different colour', 'Rated 4.1 out of 5 stars']}
]
```

I been trying to write the data into the txt file, but I couldn't figure out how to code it out. Here's what I did

```
shoes_database = open("shoes_db.txt", 'w')
for value in data:
    shoes_database.write('\n'.join([value.get('Name'), str(value.get('Date & Time')), str(value.get('Information')), '\n']))
shoes_database.close()
```

For the values in 'Name' and 'Date & Time' are stored properly into the file. However, for the 'Information' I am having trouble to store each of the shoes information into a new line and without the square brackets and '' as it is a list.

Here is what I would like to write and store in my shoes_db.txt file

```
Sneaker shoes
2019-12-03 18:21:26
Sizes from 38 to 44
Comes in 5 different colour
Rated 4.3 out of 5 stars

Worker boots
2018-11-05 10:12:15
Sizes from 38 to 44
Comes in 2 different colour
Rated 3.7 out of 5 stars

Slippers
2018-10-05 13:15:44
Sizes from 38 to 42
Comes in 3 different colour
Rated 4.1 out of 5 stars
```

Hope to have some answers to my python codes. Am still learning from it as it is part of my project. I am also restricted to the use of python standard library only, so I can't use any third-party libraries.

Comment: You probably need to write another loop inside the one you have.

Comment: Oh I see, I missed that out! thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below (The data under 'Information' is a list and you need to iterate over the list entries)

```
data = [
    {'Name': 'Sneaker shoes', 'Date & Time': '2019-12-03 18:21:26',
     'Information': ['Sizes from 38 to 44', 'Comes in 5 different colour', 'Rated 4.3 out of 5 stars']},
    {'Name': 'Worker boots', 'Date & Time': '2018-11-05 10:12:15',
     'Information': ['Sizes from 38 to 44', 'Comes in 2 different colour', 'Rated 3.7 out of 5 stars']},
    {'Name': 'Slippers', 'Date & Time': '2018-10-05 13:15:44',
     'Information': ['Sizes from 38 to 42', 'Comes in 3 different colour', 'Rated 4.1 out of 5 stars']}
]
with open("shoes_db.txt", 'w') as f:
    for idx, entry in enumerate(data):
        f.write(entry['Name'] + '\n')
        f.write(entry['Date & Time'] + '\n')
        for info in entry['Information']:
            f.write(info + '\n')
        if idx != len(data) - 1:
            f.write('\n')
```

Comment: This works great! Just one minor concern at the end of the file, there are 3 empty newlines. Is there are way to solve it?

Comment: @xeith the code was modified - give it a try again. Let me know.

Comment: Oh great it solves the problem! Sorry but could you add comments in the code so that I can better understand for the last part? about len(data) - 1 that part.
And also, how can I provide rep points to you? Am new to stack overflow

Comment: @xeith - try to ask specific question if you have.

Comment: It's this part that I am trying to understand how it works. if idx != len(data) - 1: . Thanks!

Comment: OK. `data` is a list and the code loop over it. We want to add a new line (`\n`) between the shoes but we dont to add an extra new line by the end of the file - after the last show.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("shoes_db.txt", 'w') as f:
    for entry in data:
        f.write(entry['Name'] + '\n')
        f.write(entry['Date & Time'] + '\n')
```